# Why doesn't the default XCode Window based application template create the window programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm just starting out with objective c, iphone, and xcode dev.  The default template has UIWindow *window as a member variable but I never see it initialized like:

```
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

which I'm confused as to why. Do we not need to do that because the window is already creaqted in the nib file? Thank you very much everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your app delegate's header file, just beneath the `@interface` part, you see this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
```

This connects the `window` property to the window object in your nib file, so it's already created within the nib file and there's no need to allocate a new `UIWindow` object. Your app delegate simply looks in the nib file and uses the object in there.

Comment: Oh i see, thanks. I just started and have been doing all my views programmatically and just learned about IBOutlets and IBAction s. THanks!